# Python PPTX Datalabel Fill Color

Tags: python-docx, python-pptx

```
data_labels = chart_plot.data_labels
data_labels.font.size = Pt(10)
data_labels.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 255, 255)
data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER
```

How can i access the datalabel's fill color to produce a similar fill as the image on the link below?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUI4h.png

I tried:

```
data_labels.format.fill.solid()
data_labels.format.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGB(0,164,251)
```

But not working.

Thanks.